# Regex for matching JS import statements

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I'm using node to read a file's contents. I need to match a particular import statement where the file looks something like this.

I need to match only the line or lines containing the "foo-bar" package. I'm interested in getting the imports from that package.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { foo, bar, fooBar } from 'foo-bar'
import { anotherThing } from 'another-module'
```

It can also span multiple lines like this.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { 
    foo, 
    bar, 
    fooBar 
} from 'foo-bar'
import { anotherThing } from 'another-module'
```

I've tried using this regex but it's matching all lines from "import" to the end of the line containing foo-bar. I only want to match the import to the end of the line or lines that end with "foo-bar". Is this possible using JavaScript regex? Also, if there's a better way other than using regex i'm open to other options as well

```
import([\s\S]*?)(?=foo-bar').*
```

Single line example:
https://regex101.com/r/U1j2G6/1

Multi-line example:
https://regex101.com/r/kcA7gd/1

Comment: Try `import[^']+(?= from 'foo-bar')` [here](https://regex101.com/r/U1j2G6/2) and [here](https://regex101.com/r/kcA7gd/2).

Comment: I don't have fancy links but you can try this `import(?:(?!import).)*'foo-bar'`

Comment: Start to be more precise in your descriptions in the pattern. Example: https://regex101.com/r/mqyudC/1

Comment: Another idea: [`var res = str.match(/import {\s*([^}]+)} from 'foo-bar'/)[1]`](http://jsfiddle.net/3rfdLpxm/). Also [see this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/kcA7gd/5)

Answer (score 6):

**Update**:
As @jhm2k pointed out in the answer below, there are multiple problems with the following regEx. People reading this should check his answer or [the remake I did in my github](https://github.com/antonkc/MOR/edit/main/matchJsImports.md).

---

I developed this regular expression that matches **anything** that would work as a valid import statement:

> import([ \n\t]*(?:[^ \n\t\{\}]+[ \n\t]*,?)?(?:[ \n\t]*\{(?:[
> \n\t]*[^ \n\t"'\{\}]+[ \n\t]*,?)+\})?[ \n\t]*)from[
> \n\t]*(['"])([^'"\n]+)(?:['"])

It has the following capturing groups:

- **$1** imported variables
- **$2** quotes used for the import
- **$3** import path

For your case, you could test $3.

Be careful using it since it also matches occurrences inside strings. Also, I wouldn't use it blindly, migth have bugs and it is slow.

I used the following file for testing:

```
import someClass from "src"
import someClass from"src"
import
someClass
from
"src"
import someClass
from       "src"

import {class1,class2} from "src"
import {
    class1,
    class2
            } from"src"

    import {
        class1

                } from "src"

import defaultClass   ,

{
    class1
}

  from "src"

import defaultClass,

{
    class1
}from "src"

import someClass from "src";import someClass from "src"


"I disagree about your import practices from 'src/who knows where'"
`import someClass from "src"
import someClass from"src"
import
someClass
from
"src"
import someClass
from       "src"

import {class1, class2} from "src"
import {
    class1,
    class2
            } from"src"

    import {
        class1

                } from "src"

import defaultClass   ,

{
    class1
}

  from "src"

import defaultClass,

{
    class1
}from "src"
`
```

Comment: Gives catastrophic backtracking error in regex101.com

Comment: Unless you are viewing the unedited version, it should be working. https://regex101.com/r/0s3fBy/1 (the first time I posted, I missed the fact that I had to espace some characters for it to be viewed properly.)

Comment: This works great! Thankyou! Also, props for making one of the craziest looking regex I've ever seen lol

Answer (score 3):

I got around the problem you had by using a negative capturing group - which will match as many characters as possible, up to `}`.

Here's the regex.

```
import {[^}]*}.*'foo-bar'
```

[Try it online!](https://regex101.com/r/aguDrV/1)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an updated and improved version of @Antón Kryukov Chinaev's answer:

```
import(?:(?:(?:[ \n\t]+([^ *\n\t\{\},]+)[ \n\t]*(?:,|[ \n\t]+))?([ \n\t]*\{(?:[ \n\t]*[^ \n\t"'\{\}]+[ \n\t]*,?)+\})?[ \n\t]*)|[ \n\t]*\*[ \n\t]*as[ \n\t]+([^ \n\t\{\}]+)[ \n\t]+)from[ \n\t]*(?:['"])([^'"\n]+)(['"])
```

...with support for `import * as x from 'y'` which it lacked, aswell as improved capture groups and stricter to prevent false matches such as `importx from'y'`.

The new capture groups are:

- `$1` = default import name (can be non-existent)
- `$2` = destructured exports (can be non-existent)
- `$3` = wildcard import name (can be non-existent)
- `$4` = module identifier
- `$5` = quotes used (either `'` or `"`)

[Regex101 Playground with tests used](https://regex101.com/r/FEN5ks/1)